# How to click element selected by value from variable?

Tags: cypress

I have variable:
`const tommorow = DateTime.now().plus({days:1}).toFormat('dd')`

I need to click element selected by its value:
`cy.get('#dt_hidden > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.datepicker-days > table > tbody').contains(tommorow).click()`

Element:
`<td data-action="selectDay" data-day="12.01.2022" class="day">12</td>`

My problem is that it finds 2 elements and using 'last' or eq(1) doesnt work. What should I do?

Comment: need more details on html of the page that you test

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the details of your problem, you should add some `data-testid` to elements you will be interacting to avoid brittle selectors. Depending on your app, that may simplify your problem drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `.contains(tommorow)` can easily match multiple cells when you just have a couple of digits in the text, contains() will match partially.

You have a full date in the attribute you can select

```js
const tomorrow = DateTime.now().plus({days:1}).toFormat('dd.mm.yyyy')

cy.get('#dt_hidden > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.datepicker-days > table > tbody')
  .find(`td[data-day="${tomorrow}"]`)
```

The way you calculate `tomorrow` looks strange to me, you may need to adjust it.

I would also question why `eq(1)` did not work.

---

You can make a test always run from the same fixed date, then the test is not dependent on the current date

```js
const now = new Date(2017, 3, 14).getTime()
cy.clock(now)
cy.visit(appUrl)  // set clock before visit
```

[docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Now)